# AttributeError in a pygame.sprite.Sprite subclass

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, oop, pygame

I am currently developing a 2D platformer game with pygame and I have discovered an issue. I usually handled sprite rendering with a single sprite group declared inside of the main function. Now that I need to have some specific sprites over others/under sprites, having a single group won't cut it, and having multiple groups just laying about is a mess. So I decided to add groups into my Entity class:

```
class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    entitiesTop = pygame.sprite.Group()
    entitiesMid = pygame.sprite.Group()
    entitiesBot = pygame.sprite.Group()
    entities = [entitiesBot, entitiesMid, entitiesTop]

    def __init__(self, force = None):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        if force is None:
            if isinstance(self, Platform):
                Entity.entitiesTop.add(self)
            elif isinstance(self, (Bullet, Gun)):
                Entity.entitiesMid.add(self)
            else:
                Entity.entitiesBot.add(self)
        else:
            Entity.entities[force].add(self)
```

and I made all the other subclasses of Entity automatically get added to a group using its `__init__` method. I think it was working fine with the classes, since the error didn't show when I initialized the entities themselves, rather when I tried to run this code

```
     for group in Entity.entities:
```

an `AttributeError` appeared

```
AttributeError: type object 'Entity' has no attribute 'entities'
```

I am relatively new to python OOP, so I don't quite get what I am missing here. Does anyone know the solution to this?

Comment: always show (in question) FULL error message. And always show code which makes problem. I dn't see `for group in Entity.entities:` in your code. I think you overwrite `Entity` in some place - `Entity = ...`

Comment: @furas You solved it. I really did redefine the class in the middle of the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

furas at the comments has solved the mystery. I just forgot to remove the old definition of the class! Silly me. Its all working fine now.